# Argument 'osscDetailCtaCtrl' is not aNaNunction, got undefined on reloading page with Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I got this problem when I refresh the page. This problem comes out only when I use Firefox as Browser, not when I'm using Chrome.
Can someone help me to solve this.

This is the code of my controller.

```
(function () { 
 'use strict';
    angular.module('osscApp')
    .controller('osscDetailCtaCtrl',
        ['$stateParams', 'ctaSectionsServices','PropertiesServiceOssc', 'cityServicesOssc','shareDataServices',
            function ( $stateParams, ctaSectionsServices, PropertiesServiceOssc, cityServicesOssc, shareDataServices ) {

                var vm = this;
                var apiCtaUrl = PropertiesServiceOssc.getUrl("urlOsscCtaApi");
                vm.id = $stateParams.id;
                var ctaDetailUrl = apiCtaUrl + vm.id + "/detail"; 

                vm.url = apiCtaUrl; 
                vm.disabled = true;

                vm.message = "";
                vm.alertClass = "";

                vm.data = {};

                vm.filesCore = [];
                vm.filesCentre = [];
                vm.filesAuthority = [];
                vm.filesCta = [];

                var object = shareDataServices.get( vm.id + 'CTA' );
                var eventId = object && object.eventId ? ( Array.isArray ( object.eventId ) ? 0 : object.eventId ) : 0;

                vm.countries = [];
                cityServicesOssc.getCountries( function ( response ){
                    if( response ){
                        vm.countries = response;
                    }
                });

                vm.memberStates = [];
                cityServicesOssc.getMemberStates( function ( response ){
                    if( response ){
                        vm.memberStates = response;
                    }
                });

                vm.regions = [];
                cityServicesOssc.getRegions( 117, function ( response ){
                    if( response ){
                        vm.regions = response;
                    }
                });

                ctaSectionsServices.getCta( ctaDetailUrl + "/" + eventId, function ( response, errors ){
                    if( response ){
                            vm.data = response;
                    }else{
                        vm.message = errors.message;
                        vm.alertClass = errors.alertClass;
                    }
                });             
            }
        ]);
})();
```

Here's a browser console screenshoot.

[image]

Comment: is it the only js file that you are refering?

Comment: yes, the error refering this controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough study, I found the cause and consequently the solution to this problem. In my project, I use lazy load dependencies through ocLazyLoad with ui-router for changing states in my "app.js". I noticed that not always in lazy load loading the libraries are loaded in the same order as they were defined, so if controller A uses a service B theoretically, the service B and finally the controller A should be loaded. Unfortunately, although the dependencies are declared in the correct sequence, often ocLazyLoad load them apparently in random order, so sometimes loaded first B service and then A controller (and site navigation continued correctly), sometimes load first A controller(and run it) and then B service breaking the app and firing in browser's console errors similar to those shown above. This second case occurred especially when refreshing pages with Firefox browsers (on every refresh and sometimes even during some state changes). To solve this problem, I declared the dependencies for each application state, by forcing them to load in series using the parameter "serie: true" of ocLazyLoad.
Previous Code:

```
//the dependencies are loaded in random order on refresh state ( break the app)
$stateProvider.state('ossc.ctaDetail', {
                url: '/clinicalTrial/:id/detail',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: '{{"DETAIL_CTA" | translate}}',
                    parent: 'ossc.searchCta'
                },
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: './modules/ossc/html/cta/osscDetailCta.html',
                        controller: 'osscDetailCtaCtrl',
                        controllerAs: 'ctaCtrl'
                    },
                    'menu': {
                        templateUrl: './modules/menu/html/menu.html',
                        controller: 'menuCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    translate: ['RequireTranslations', function( RequireTranslations ){
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta, translationApp );
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta + '/'+ translationSelect , translationApp );
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta + '/'+ translationTitles , translationApp );
                    }],                   
                    '':['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad){
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                                        name:'dependencies',
                                        files:[
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/ctaSectionsServices.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/propertiesServiceOssc.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/shareDataServices.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/controllers/cta/osscDetailCtaCtrl.js',
                                            ],
                        });
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Adopted Solution:

```
$stateProvider.state('ossc.ctaDetail', {
                url: '/clinicalTrial/:id/detail',
                ncyBreadcrumb: {
                    label: '{{"DETAIL_CTA" | translate}}',
                    parent: 'ossc.searchCta'
                },
                views: {
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: './modules/ossc/html/cta/osscDetailCta.html',
                        controller: 'osscDetailCtaCtrl',
                        controllerAs: 'ctaCtrl'
                    },
                    'menu': {
                        templateUrl: './modules/menu/html/menu.html',
                        controller: 'menuCtrl'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    translate: ['RequireTranslations', function( RequireTranslations ){
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta, translationApp );
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta + '/'+ translationSelect , translationApp );
                        RequireTranslations( translationCta + '/'+ translationTitles , translationApp );
                    }],                   
                    '':['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad){
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                    {
                                        name:'dependencies',
                                        files:[
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/ctaSectionsServices.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/propertiesServiceOssc.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/shareDataServices.js',
                                            'modules/ossc/js/services/ctaSectionsServices.js',
                                            ],
                                        serie:true,
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name:'controller',
                                        files:[
                                            'modules/ossc/js/controllers/cta/osscDetailCtaCtrl.js',
                                            ],
                                        serie:true,
                                    }
                            ]);
                    }]
                }
            })
```

I hope this solution can help someone who has my own problems.

Answer (score 0):

It should happen in chrome too,

Make sure you have the empty dependencies added to your module,

```
 angular.module('osscApp',[])
```

Comment: Not happen in Chrome. The empty dependencies should be added when you are going to define a new module, not in this case because this controller is part of an existing module. The module that you refer, 'osscApp', is correctly defined with all dependencies in another js file.